# Why is pyAutoGui not clicking in certain windows

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a python program to Automate the setup of a new computer. I used pyAutoGui to click on the Install button when prompted but it wont click on the button. It detects the image "Install.png" because it breaks the while loop when Adobe prompts to install. I tested it in paint and if I change the Install.png image to something on paint I can visually see it clicks. I tried the mouse library, moving it to the coordinates and then clicking, double- tripleClick, MouseDown -> sleep -> MouseUp, just MouseDown -> MouseUp, sending enter with pyAutogui, sending enter with shell, using subprocess and some other stuff. Nothing seems to work on the popup window Adobe gives. I printed the coordinates and they come out fine (I used DisplayMouseInfo to see of the coordinates were correct) I even hard coded the coordinates but it doesnt click install. Any answers would be appreciated, here is how it looks.

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import psutil
import pyautogui as pg
import time 

global path
path = os.getcwd()

def adobe_install():

    adobe_setup_path = os.path.join(path, "Adobe.exe")
    adobe_cmd = str("start " + adobe_setup_path)
    os.system(adobe_cmd)

    while pg.locateCenterOnScreen('Install.png', confidence=0.9) == None:
        wait

    time.sleep(2)

    clk= pg.locateCenterOnScreen('Install.png', confidence=0.9)

    pg.click(clk.x, clk.y)
```

**EDIT**
I tried the following
Install is just the a screenshot of the install button and the coordinates it prints (clk.x ; clk.y) are correct

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import pyautogui as pg
import time 
import pathlib
import winreg
import win32con
import win32gui

def adobe_install():

    adobe_setup_path = os.path.join(path, "Adobe.exe")
    adobe_cmd = str("start " + adobe_setup_path)
    os.system(adobe_cmd)
    while pg.locateCenterOnScreen('Install.png', confidence=0.9) == None:
        wait

    results = []
    top_windows = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, top_windows)
    for i in top_windows:
        if "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (Continuous) - Setup" in i[1]:
            print(i)
            win32gui.ShowWindow(i[0],5)
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])
            bring_to_front(i[0])
            break
    
    time.sleep(2)

    clk= pg.locateCenterOnScreen('Install.png', confidence=0.9)

    print(clk.x)
    print(clk.y)

    pg.click(clk.x, clk.y)
    pg.leftClick(x=clk.x, y=clk.y)

    pg.typewrite(['enter'], interval=1)

adobe_install()
```

I tried clicking, left clicking, and pressing enter. I tested the in other windows like Paint and word and the clicking and they all did indeed click or send "Enter"

This is the error I recieved

```
File "C:\Users\***\documents\ict\software\New_comp.py", line 77, in adobe_install
    bring_to_front(i[0])
  File "C:\Users\***\documents\ict\software\New_comp.py", line 41, in bring_to_front
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
pywintypes.error: (5, 'SetWindowPos', 'Access is denied.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bringing the window to front & activate it. But you need to put in the window handler

```
import win32gui
import win32con

def bringTOfront(HWND):
        win32gui.ShowWindow(HWND, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(HWND, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW + win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
```

Comment: Hi, no its not. There are multiple function definitions. Adobe_install is just one of them. Thanks

Comment: After you run `os.system(adobe_cmd)` what window popped up? Is it windows asking for admin log in? Or Adobe window?

Comment: I change the answer please try it. It brings the windows to front and activates it

Comment: The adobe window pops up. I'll try the answer asap

Comment: I'm not familiar with passing windows into a window handler. How would you do that? When I ask Dr. Google I get a lot of answers on Selenium.... Would that work and if it would how would you do that?

Comment: I tried your answer and got an Access is Denied error. I also tried ```win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])``` but it still didnt click on the install button.

Comment: Selenium is if you're working with web browsers and html. I don't think that's what you need.

SetForegroundWindow didn't work for me as well. You have to use win32gui.SetWindowPos. At which line did you get the Access is Denied error? Can you edit your problem and add what have you tried & the result